# I am using php include to call my header but when I change my header background color it changes my entire site

Tags: header, include

I am new to php, the only sites that I have built didn't use any php or dynamic content. I believe I need to build a container but my attempts have failed. I can't use a table because I need a table centered within the header.

What I am trying to do should be easy. I want to build a header with a navbar in it quite like stackoverflows actually. I call my header using include, currently my header just includes some log in message code and calls my login class code.

I can figure out the code if someone just tells me the basic concept of what I'm trying to do. I tried a div. Table isn't my solution. I've seen answers on here with other containers and separate css files but I really didn't understand.

Header code. No formatting yet.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<?php
// show potential errors / feedback (from login object)
if (isset($login)) {
    if ($login->errors) {
        foreach ($login->errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
    if ($login->messages) {
        foreach ($login->messages as $message) {
            echo $message;
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php
// show potential errors / feedback (from registration object)
if (isset($registration)) {
    if ($registration->errors) {
        foreach ($registration->errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
    if ($registration->messages) {
        foreach ($registration->messages as $message) {
            echo $message;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

That is how it looks when I start and my php code works fine.

I am trying to do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome to SafeLog</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        /* just for the demo */
        body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 10px;
        }
        label {
            position: relative;
            vertical-align: middle;
            bottom: 1px;
        }
        input[type=text],
        input[type=password],
        input[type=submit],
        input[type=email] {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
        input[type=checkbox] {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }
    #apDiv1 {
    position:absolute;
    width:1745px;
    height:115px;
    z-index:1;
    left: -10px;
    top: 4px;
}
    #apDiv2 {
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:30px;
    z-index:1;
    background-color: #333333;
}
    .texttest {
    color: #FFF;
}
    </style>

   <body>
   <div style="width:auto" style="height:30" style="background-color:333333">
   <body>

<?php
// show potential errors / feedback (from login object)
if (isset($login)) {
    if ($login->errors) {
        foreach ($login->errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
    if ($login->messages) {
        foreach ($login->messages as $message) {
            echo $message;
        }
    }
}
?>

<?php
// show potential errors / feedback (from registration object)
if (isset($registration)) {
    if ($registration->errors) {
        foreach ($registration->errors as $error) {
            echo $error;
        }
    }
    if ($registration->messages) {
        foreach ($registration->messages as $message) {
            echo $message;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

everything is working fine besides that div. I am not very good with css and html, I used to be a vb developer making small in house solutions for business.

Comment: You might try including some of the code you have tried in your question as a pointer to what people need to help you with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited--

Actually its your div tag only...

Make it

```
style="background-color:#333;"
```

in the div

Comment: Der, that was dumb of me. Yeah it is fixed now lol. I've seriously been banging my head on the wall for hours over this lmao. Thank you. This is the first time I used stack, I always read it. Never wanted to look like an idiot when asking a question. My biggest fear realized lol. Thank you!

Comment: Its okay. Glad to help you. Please put a tick on this as an answer if it fixed ur problem. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use HTML to lay out then use CSS to style and position it?

Comment: My HTML is failing me. I must have something wrong. When I change the background color of the header every single one of my views change as well. It's not a very large site and I was attempting to use MVC framework. I mentioned that I tried creating a div and setting it with css, it still changed my entire site. I'm mystified. I'm probably just gonna scrap how I wanted it and float my nav in the center of white space, it's just not what I envisioned. I'm using CS5 and my experience has been limited to the design view. I figured I could just change the header bg color and all would be well.

Comment: @user3342848 Due to you not showing what you have done i'm finding it hard to help resolve this situation, as far as im aware you could have a tag not properly closed

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize I couldn't make another post with my code for 8 hours :/ Is a division tag my answer?

Comment: I read something about building a container on each view to display my header but it really messed up my login system. I'm sure I'll Figure it out. But like I said, I'm starting with a blank slate, all that is in my header.php is php code at this point.

Comment: @user3342828 Perhaps it is dude, but i am not sure because i cant see what you have done so far! Edit your question and paste the code there?

Comment: I can add whatever formatting into it at this point. I just don't know what to use. I just want my header to be 100% wide and 30 pixels tall and have a different color background.

Comment: I added the code without formatting and then added the code for what I was trying to do above.